# Can we use javascript variables which are defined in callback functions, outside of it(callback function)?

Tags: javascript, variables, callback

This is my code.

```
var scoreResults = document.querySelectorAll(".flex-blackjack-row-1 h3");
var scores = document.querySelector(".flex-blackjack-row-1 span");

const config = {childList: true};

const busted = function (mutationList, observer){
    
        var bustedMessage = document.createElement('h2');
        bustedMessage.textContent = 'BUSTED!';
        scoreResults[0].before(bustedMessage);
        hitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(busted);
observer.observe(scores, config);
```

I have defined **bustedMessage** variable in a callback function and I want to use it outside of that callback function. Still after successfully invoking the busted function (that means still after initiating the **bustedMessage** variable ), that variable can not be used outside of the callback function.

But when I take out this code block,

```
    var bustedMessage = document.createElement('h2');
    bustedMessage.textContent = 'BUSTED!';
```

to the outside from **"busted" callback function**, I can use **bustedMessage** variable in other functions too. Please explain why is this happening? I can not understand it because **bustedMessage** is a **var** type variable which is ought to use in anywhere.

Comment: Have you try returning the **bustedMessage** in the end of the function?

Comment: You can learn it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp)

Comment: I just realize it's a callback func, so returning the variable not gonna work. Answering your question about why the bustedMessage doesn't work on the outside is because of variable scope. Your bustedMessage is a **Local Scope** variable, so it can't be used outside that function, more info in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: If u want to use the variable outside the function u can use **Automatically Global** variable, the explanation is in the link I provide in the previous comment

Comment: @DeanTristaNato Thanks. Actually I know how to do Automatically Global variable. I wanted to know why doesn't var work outside of the function. Following the link that you provided now I know that there is something called **Function Scope**. Even though what you said is wrong (It is not local scope instead function scope) you push me to the correct track. So I'm gonna vote your comment as a useful one. But consider to replace **Local scope** as **function scope**

Answer (score 0):

Define `bustedMessage` outside first

```js
var bustedMessage;

const busted = function (mutationList, observer){
    
        bustedMessage = document.createElement('h2');
        bustedMessage.textContent = 'BUSTED!';
        scoreResults[0].before(bustedMessage);
        hitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    
}
```

you are now free to use bustedMessage anywhere in this script, of course it's undefined until you call `busted` for the first time.

Comment: I can undrestand that this code block is working finely. But I want to understand why my code is not working. If you can give any help...